# Serial data logger, parse on the fly

Tags: python, sql, pyserial

I am trying to slap together a Python data logger and am looking for some advice.  Here is my situation.
I don't want any user intervention.  Just plug in and record.  So far I am using the PySerial module and am able to record all serial data to a text file just fine. I read one line, store in a variable, then write that variable to a file in append mode.

Now I would like to transmit this data to the web for graphing.  Here is where my headache comes in.  Should I try and send this to a SQL server or just to a text file?  I am using a 3g module, but speeds/bandwidth are limited.  Data is streaming to the logger at 1 sample every .25sec  Here is an example:

1 324 23454 2342 0 233 0 0 12223 66453 443 33 33 20 0 0 0 0

So I don't think I need to send EVERY sample, maybe just one line per second or every other second.

The logger will only run for about 5 days then all data will be recorded.  Now my questions are, are there any recommendations on how/where I should send the data?  SQL or Text file?  And next, if I have this data online, is there an easy to way to plot this data in real-time while it is streaming?

And for the icing on the cake, sometimes the raw data will be space delimited, sometimes tab delimited, and sometimes comma delimited.

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: What is your power source? Is battery preservation an issue of concern at all?

Comment: Currently pluged into an AC outlet, so power is not a concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you have a bunch of questions/issues here. I will try and address each of them:

**Database**

keep each line in a table in a database. It will make your life much easier. I recommend use something that can handle big loads like MySQL or Postgres. I could suggest the following table design. `line` is your data, `uploaded` is a flag which indicates whether or not this line has been uploaded to the server yet. `line_date` can record the exact date time that the reading was taken, that might be useful to capture. If your data lines are variable and you don't want to set a fixed length change the varchar(200) to text. I recommend you keep this table on the client side and use the uploaded field as a flag to indicate whether or not this line has been uploaded to the server. That way you won't have any data loss during any network connectivity issues, and you can keep track of which lines are still pending an upload. You can then have one script that just inserts lines, another script or thread that reads the list of not uploaded rows and uploads them every second or so. You can also have pretty much the same table design on the server for simplicity.

```
CREATE TABLE data_lines (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    line VARCHAR(200),
    uploaded INT,
    line_date DATETIME
);
```

**Parsing lines**

You mentioned the raw data will be space delimited, sometimes tab delimited, and sometimes comma delimited. This simple line of code can handle all those cases.

```
>>> line = "1,2 3\t4"
>>> print line.replace(',', ' ').split()
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

**Real-Time graphs**

[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) is the way to go. They do really great web-based real time graphs. you can see an [example of one here](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/realtime.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for the update!  Now you mentioned storing the entire string of data on the database under "line".  Would it not be better (at lease for the future and plotting) to parse each sensor reading into its own column?   Not sure if that makes sense or not, but my data string "1 342 355 234 2432" each number represents a value from an individual sensor.  The first column is my timestamp, second is pressure, third is temp, etc.  Each time I move my data recorder to a new location, there is a different # of sensors.  First location may have 5, next may have 30.

Comment: you could go with that option, have a column called temp, pressure, etc. But since you don't have a fixed set of columns I wouldn't since they may have 5 or it might be 30 fields in a location. It seems simpler to insert the data in a single column that is lets say comma delimited, and the split each time you retrieve the data.

Comment: Very good point.  Thank you for your help, Ill get to work and see what happens! Thanks again

Comment: So I took your advice, and I am sending my sensor data in realtime to MySQL server.  Working great!  Now I am trying to find some info on using Flot.  I cant seem to find a good example or step by step tutorial to follow.  Do you have any pointers or references I could look at?

Comment: @user1876087 I haven't used it myself, I just googled but couldn't find much about it. I recommend you post another question asking for a link to a tutorial or better yet a simple working example. In your case you could also post your mysql table schema and some code you have tried.

Comment: Ok, so now that I have my data on the SQL server, I am trying to plot it.  I have been playing with Flot and HighCharts.  Both will plot Time vs 1Sensor.  But my problem is how my SQL dbase is setup.  In the table, I have three columns.  1 is ID, 2 is TimeStamp, 3 is Sensor Values.  I am reading about 15 sensors and they all output data to that on field.  Ex.  (243.2 98.5 22 344.2 344.3 etc...)  The First is pressure, second is temp, etc.  Now I need to make multiple plots, one for each sensor.  Is this possible?

Comment: @user1876087 it is possible, I would post some sample code and data in a new question and show how far you've got.